# Read facebook lead ads - only one lead in response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I test on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

My query: /v2.8/11111111/leadgen_forms?fields=leads_count,leads

Response:

```
{ "data": [
{
  "name": "My Form",
  "leads_count": 37,
  "leads": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2016-12-21T14:50:56+0000",
        "id": "10000000000000",
        "field_data": [
          {
            "name": "email",
            "values": [
              "hidden@gmail.com"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "first_name",
            "values": [
              "Hidden"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "last_name",
            "values": [
              "Hidden"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTc0ODU4Mjg2MjEyODQ1MgZDZD",
        "after": "MTc0ODU4Mjg2MjEyODQ1MgZDZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "10000000000000"
}
}
```

Why I get only one lead in data, when I have 37 in leads_count field?

Comment: Did you check MTc0ODU4Mjg2MjEyODQ1MgZDZD page?

Comment: @Nakilon For query: v2.8/10000000000000/leads?after=MTc0ODU4Mjg2MjEyODQ1MgZDZD  response data is empty: {"data":[]}

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't see the way you are accessing leads documented anywhere.

In your request, you are accessing the edge of a page, requesting the forms, and within that, requesting the leads.

You should probably be using the edge of the form ID instead to retrieve leads:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<FORM_ID>/leads
```

You can also filter them:

```
curl -G \
  -d "filtering=[{'field':'time_created','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':<TIMESTAMP>}]" \
  -d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<AD_ID>/leads
```

Comment: I have a similar request working, filtering by time_created, but I'd like to filter by id instead - replacing the values as follows: filtering=[{"field":"id","operator":"GREATER_THAN","value":"115928369075701"}].  However, I get an unknown error has occurred.  I've tried a number of variations, but without success.  Can you tell me the appropriate syntax for id filtering?